# google books api getJSON returns syntax error

Tags: jquery, json, google-api, syntax-error

I have the following problem I am working on for days now.
I want to make a json request from the Google Books API.

Using Firefox' Firebug Developer Tools, the console says **"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"** and is showing me the returned text: **{"number_of_results"*:*63,"search_results":[{"page_id":"PA33",** and so on.

It seems that the returned json is invalid (I checked it, it is *valid*). However in the network-tab Firefox is getting (or creating?) a json-object from the GET statement to examine in the JSON-tab. Even if the google-server returns JSON and I am expecting JSONP, why can I examine a JSON-object in Firebug?

If Firefox is showing me the json-object, why am I getting this error and cannot create a json-object myself at runtime? Thanks in advance!

```
function searchInBook(){

    var newUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0738531367&someting&callback=?';
    $.ajax({
        url: newUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            bookId = data.items[0].id;
            console.log("received book-id:" + bookId);
            bookUrl = "http://books.google.de/books?id="+bookId+"&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&jscmd=SearchWithinVolume&q="+searchquery+"&scoring=r#v=onepage&q&f=false&myCallback=?";
            console.log(bookUrl);

            $.ajax({
                url: bookUrl,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(bookData){
                    $("#json-result").html(JSON.stringify(bookData));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(bookData));
                },
                error: function( foo ) {
                  console.log( "ERROR:  " + foo );
                }
            });
        },
        error: function( foo ) {
          alert( "ERROR:  " + foo );
        }
    });     

}
```

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJVux/. Are you encoding your search query parameter?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Sorry, I am relatively new to javascript. Could you please explain what you mean by encoding, i.e. how to do that?

Comment: In the assignment of `bookUrl`, try changing `+searchquery+` to `+encodeURIComponent(searchquery)+`. Not sure if that will fix it, but probably good practice anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately encoding didn't help. Why is this working in the fiddle but not in my local script?

Comment: That's a good question. What is the search term you're using?

Comment: I did "the" as well. The network GET request in the fiddle is http://books.google.de/books?id=Py8u3Obs4f4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&jscmd=SearchWithinVolume&q=the&scoring=r&callback=jQuery20207980013451975059_1385042188756&_=1385042188758 and locally I get http://books.google.de/books?id=Py8u3Obs4f4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&jscmd=SearchWithinVolume&q=the&scoring=r#v=onepage&q&f=false&myCallback=jsonp1385042049341&_=1385042214178. It seems that jQuery is generating another callback in the fiddle

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure why it is working in the fiddle, but I'm pretty sure the `#` in the url is throwing it off for you. The browser thinks that what follows that is the hash fragment, so the following parameters should be ignored. Should that be a `&` instead?

Comment: The strange thing is that you pasted my code exactly into the fiddle and jquery is parsing it correctly and throws the hashtag away. I tried with a '&'

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the fiddle and the searchquery. First I used an very old version of jQuery and second I passed the searchquery incorrectly from my input field. How can I give kudos to you?

Comment: Gah! I was about to ask what version of jquery you were using. Glad you figured it out.